# Buy and sell of my tokens

Tags: dapp-development, ethereum-wallet-dapp, tokens

How to implement the buy of tokens. That is, the customer transfers money to the address and receives tokens at his account. And Similar to sold?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to deploy a Solidity Smart Contract of your own tokens like this:

https://www.ethereum.org/token